# Получить все элементы DOM которые не оборачивают нужный элемент

Tags: javascript, dom

Как на JS получить все элементы внутри body, котрые не оборачиваю элемент (#elem), и не находятся внутри него?

```
<div>
    <div></div> <!-- Получить -->
    <div id='elem'>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div></div> <!-- Получить -->
</div>
<div></div> <!-- Получить -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getNodesExcept(node)
{
 var body=document.body;
 var allNodes=new Array;
 function testNode(n)
  {
   var ch=n.childNodes;
   for (var i=0; i < ch.length; i++)
    {
      if(ch[i].nodeName=='#text' || ch[i].nodeName=='#comment' ||
         ch[i].nodeName=='SCRIPT' || ch[i].nodeName=='STYLE') continue;
      if(ch[i]==node) continue;
      var nxt=false;
      for(var e=node.parentNode; e && e!=body; e=e.parentNode)
       { if(e==ch[i]) {nxt=true;} }
      testNode(ch[i]);
      if(!nxt) allNodes.push(ch[i]);
    }
  }
 testNode(body);
 return allNodes;
}
```

Использовать передавая сам объект исключаемой ноды, `getNodesExcept(document.getElementById('elem'));`
Вернет все интересующие ноды, включая всех из детей. В данном примере ноды типа: текст, комментарии, скрипты и стили исключаются.

Comment: Спасибо, так работает! Как правильно добавить фильтр по типу в цикл (нужны одни теги), подскажите пожалуйста..

Comment: Что то типа ch[i].nodeName='DIV', например. Как конкретные ноды называются надо уже по факту смотреть. Особенно если не только div нужны. А если только div, то может их просто отобрать по getElementsByTagName и бежать циклом по ним, а не по всему body, как у меня сейчас

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, приведите пожалуйста пример, где возвращаются не только ноды верхнего уровня, но и все, включая детей. Элементы нужны все, кроме: text, comment, style и script.

Comment: Поправил ответ. В следующий раз старайтесь изначально в вопросе  такие нюансы указывать. В данном случае решение это позволило легко, но от таких нюансов вообще подход к решению задачи может меняться.И про IE8, кстати то же, у меня изначально, пока я это делал был более короткий вариант, но конкретно в IE8 он был нерабочим ...

Answer (score 0):

Немного изменил, чтобы было видно что выбирает селектор:

```js
var el = document.body.querySelectorAll(':not(#elem)>:empty');

console.log(Array.prototype.map.call(el, function(e) {
  return e.getAttribute('data-text');
}).join());
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-text="1"></div> <!-- Получить -->
  <div id='elem' data-text="2">
    <div data-text="3"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-text="4"></div> <!-- Получить -->
</div>
<div data-text="5"></div> <!-- Получить -->
```

Comment: Не знаю как автору вопроса, важно это или нет. Но если в `<div data-text="3">` вложить еще 1 div то он будет выдан этим селектором. И если внутри `<div data-text="5">` вложить еще div, то на выходе будет только вложенный, но НЕ сам `<div data-text="5">`

Comment: Aleksander K. спасибо за пример, но Mike абсолютно верно подметил, это важно. Забыл сказать что html разметка заранее не известна, и могут быть любые вложения. И ещё, нужно что бы в IE8+ работало.